# Custom UserDetailService circular reference with GlobalMethodSecurity

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-java-config

I'm trying to convert our security.xml to JavaConfig

```
**
 *  <security:global-method-security
 secured-annotations="enabled"
 jsr250-annotations="enabled"
 access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager">
 </security:global-method-security>
 */
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity( jsr250Enabled = true, securedEnabled = true )
public class SecurityConfig
{
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    /**
     *  <bean id="accessDecisionManager"
     class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased">
     <constructor-arg>
     <list>
     <bean class="com.myapp.security.access.voter.MyAppRoleVoter">
     <property name="rolePrefix" value="" />
     </bean>
     <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter" />
     </list>
     </constructor-arg>
     </bean>
     */
    @Bean
    AccessDecisionManager accessDecisionManager( ) {
        return new AffirmativeBased( Collections.singletonList( new MyAppRoleVoter() ) );
    }

    /**
     *  <security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
     <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="clientDetailsUserService"/>
     <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="principalService">
     <security:password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder" />
     </security:authentication-provider>
     </security:authentication-manager>
     */
    @Autowired
    void configureGlobal(
        final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth,
        @Qualifier( PasswordEncryptionConfig.PASSWORD_ENCODER ) final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder
    ) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService( userDetailsService ).passwordEncoder( passwordEncoder );
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setUserDetailsService(
        @Qualifier( PrincipalService.BEAN_ID ) final UserDetailsService userDetailsService )
    {
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
    }
}
```

This exception isn't particularly surprising

```
 Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void com.myapp.config.SecurityConfig.setUserDetailsService(org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'methodSecurityInterceptor': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
```

How can I write my javaconfig so that it does the same thing as the previous XML? (Update: at the time of this writing this is occurring in Spring Security 4.0.4 on Platform BOM 2.0.5)

Comment: What happens if you just inject the UserDetailsService in the configureGlobal method (the same way as the PasswordEncoder) instead of injecting it on a setter of the configuration class?

Comment: Same problem circular reference

Comment: Can you a) try w/ the latest snapshot as I this might have been resolved in 4.1.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT. If that doesn't help, you can also try removing configureGlobal as this isn't necessary in Spring Security 4.1.0 (you only need to expose UserDetailsService and PasswordEncoder as beans)

Comment: @RobWinch well migrating to 4.1.1 and removing the method removes the exception... but I can't login, looking at the configuration I have I think that should still work... so I'm currently trying to discern whether I have a misconfiguration or whether it's not doing anything at all. Judging by our logs it's not even trying to login, but looking for the spring security debug logging setting.

Comment: @RobWinch `@EnableWebSecurity( debug = true )` added that but it doesn't seem to provide more information. created a method to `@Autowire` `List<AuthenticationManager> and see an instance of AuthenticationManagerDelegator that has no defaultUserDetailService, and there are 3 UserDetailService's (oauth, saml, password)

Comment: @RobWinch `org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderNotFoundException: No AuthenticationProvider found for org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken`

so I would say it's no longer trying to register these at all... regardless of the presence of the `configureGlobal` method

Comment: @RobWinch after some more finagling with the configs got it authenticating with some CSRF failures, but that's just more configuration that hasn't been done, looks like it is loading.

I still did the configureGlobal, I think that has to be done because we have multiple userDetail/and configurations

we are going to have to punt on this because it's not out yet.

Comment: @xenoterracide You are right that if you have multiple UserDetailsService it requires either a single AuthenticationProvider bean or use of configureGlobal. NOTE: I'm in the process of releasing Spring Security 4.1.1 which will be announced tomorrow.